# How to create app for nokia phones running android like for Nokia XL etc

Tags: android, nokia, nokiax

I have created an android app. When I connect my Nokia XL (having android OS) with USB debugging enabled, my eclipse can't detect it, and runs the app on the emulator whereas I want it to be running on my cell phone. On the other hand, it works perfectly when any other android cell phone is connected.

Any help will be life saving for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows you have to install the driver first. Please see [here](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/getting-started/device-setup.html) for more details.

Follow [this](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/getting-started/device-setup.html#toc_Windowsspecificsteps) steps, If your operating system is Windows.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't follow it because there is no link to the software. Isn't there any video tutorial that you can share. It'll be a great favor by you.

Comment: What is your operating system ?

Comment: Check the steps for windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

Download *ADB Driver Installer* from [adbdriver.com/downloads/](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/) and unzip the package. Make sure you have enabled the developer options and USB debugging in your mobile, and connect to computer. Then, run *ADBDriverInstaller.exe* from the extracted folder. Select the device and click on *Install*. It worked perfectly for me. My device was then recognized. Hope it helps others with same problem.